# Fragments, How to overlay Fragment layout to an existing Layout XML and vice-a-versa?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my App, an Activity having a layout xml (first page) inflates onCreate method. On some event(like button click), i want to use Fragment class, and inflate layout xml via Fragments, on the above said layout xml as a container. like below , is my layout xml(first page).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button ... . >


</FrameLayout>
```

On Button click, i want to use Fragments within the same Layout container. So i use below code in Activity (on button click).

```
FragmentManager fManager= getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
fTransaction.replace(R.id.container,frag);
fTransaction.commit();
```

Now, new layout via Fragment is visible but the old layout is also in the background and visible.

I **don't want** to use Fragments from the very first layout, as i am doing.
I want to inflate a layout xml first, then on some event, use Fragments layout, and again , from Fragments , i want to switch to Layout xml, means vice-a-versa.

like,

```
Layout xml inflate via setContentView() -> layout via Fragments -> Layout xml inflate via setContentView()
```

How to hide or make invisible layout xml (first page) when Fragment layout gets inflates and vice-a-versa ?

Comment: when you inflate one fragment if you just want to hide the other fragment you can just make it invisible for awhile.  To do this you would get the view and set its visibility

Answer (score 0):

If the fragment covers the whole screen, you can set the background of the fragment a solid color.